# Lumen: Generate Model validation rules

Tags: laravel, lumen

Artisan generator seems over-sophisticated, It generates a class extended from Model class!!!

> Is there any way to generate model validation rules in a lumen model automatically (based on column definition of a mysql table)?
>
> What about column names?

Comment: Dear down-voter I'm sorry to be intrepid, in common sense, model generation is supposed to handle some basic features like validation!

Answer (score 4):

I am the author of [lumen-generators](https://github.com/webNeat/lumen-generators), A collection of generators for Lumen and Laravel 5.

This package contains a [Model Generator](https://github.com/webNeat/lumen-generators#model-generator) which supports generating validation rules.

### Installation

Add the generators package to your composer.json by running the command:

`composer require wn/lumen-generators`

Then add the service provider in the file `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` like the following:

```
public function register()
{
    if ($this->app->environment() == 'local') {
        $this->app->register('Wn\Generators\CommandsServiceProvider');
    }
}
```

**Don't forget to include the application service provider on your `bootstrap/app.php` and to enable Eloquent and Facades if you are using Lumen**

If you run the command `php artisan list` you will see the list of added commands:

```
wn:controller               Generates RESTful controller using the RESTActions trait
wn:controller:rest-actions  Generates REST actions trait to use into controllers
wn:migration                Generates a migration to create a table with schema
wn:model                    Generates a model class for a RESTfull resource
wn:pivot-table              Generates creation migration for a pivot table
wn:resource                 Generates a model, migration, controller and routes for RESTful resource
wn:resources                Generates multiple resources from a file
wn:route                    Generates RESTful routes.
```

### Generating a model with validation rules

Runing the following command:

```
php artisan wn:model TestingModel --rules="name=required age=integer|min:13 email=email|unique:users,email_address"
```

Will generate a model containing the following rules:

```
public static $rules = [
    "name" => "required",
    "age" => "integer|min:13",
    "email" => "email|unique:users,email_address",
];
```

Please refer to the [Full README](https://github.com/webNeat/lumen-generators) for more details.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: The thing is that I still need to mention validation rules, that would be great if generator can extract basic rules out of mysql definitions.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such command built into laravel or lumen.

I found a package (on a site called google) that provides such a command: https://github.com/jijoel/validation-rule-generator

It's locked to illuminate/support 4.0.x, so won't work with current versions of laravel. If you have lots of models it might be worth to fork, bump the version in composer.json and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout **Laravel Schema Rules** for that:

https://github.com/laracraft-tech/laravel-schema-rules

**Installation**

```
composer require laracraft-tech/laravel-schema-rules --dev
```

Let's say you've migrated this fictional table:

```php
Schema::create('persons', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('first_name', 100);
    $table->string('last_name', 100);
    $table->string('email');
    $table->foreignId('address_id')->constrained();
    $table->text('bio')->nullable();
    $table->enum('gender', ['m', 'f', 'd']);
    $table->date('birth');
    $table->year('graduated');
    $table->float('body_size');
    $table->unsignedTinyInteger('children_count')->nullable();
    $table->integer('account_balance');
    $table->unsignedInteger('net_income');
    $table->boolean('send_newsletter')->nullable();
});
```

Now if you run:

```
php artisan schema:generate-rules persons
```

You'll get:

```
Schema-based validation rules for table "persons" have been generated!
Copy & paste these to your controller validation or form request or where ever your validation takes place:
[
    'first_name' => ['required', 'string', 'min:1', 'max:100'],
    'last_name' => ['required', 'string', 'min:1', 'max:100'],
    'email' => ['required', 'string', 'min:1', 'max:255'],
    'address_id' => ['required', 'exists:addresses,id'],
    'bio' => ['nullable', 'string', 'min:1'],
    'gender' => ['required', 'string', 'in:m,f,d'],
    'birth' => ['required', 'date'],
    'graduated' => ['required', 'integer', 'min:1901', 'max:2155'],
    'body_size' => ['required', 'numeric'],
    'children_count' => ['nullable', 'integer', 'min:0', 'max:255'],
    'account_balance' => ['required', 'integer', 'min:-2147483648', 'max:2147483647'],
    'net_income' => ['required', 'integer', 'min:0', 'max:4294967295'],
    'send_newsletter' => ['nullable', 'boolean']
]
```